# Passing a list from AngularJS to Spring Controller

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am calling a Spring API from AngularJS, where I am trying to pass a list of model object as the param.

```
data.append('updatedItems', $scope.QuoteList);
$http.post('updateQuotes', data).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Then in Spring controller, I am trying to receive as below,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateQuotes", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ArrayList<ConsumerPrice> updateQuotes(@RequestBody List<ConsumerPrice> updatedItems, ConsumerPrice consumerPrice) {
    System.out.println(updatedItems);
    return null;
}
```

At this point, I get an exception as mentioned below. I am not sure if this is the correct approach to pass a list from Angular to Spring controller.

```
Invalid mime type "application/json;charset=utf-8, multipart/form-data;
```

I found few guidance in the internet and tried like, providing the consumes header but nothing helped. Any guidance will be great

I tried providing @PathVariable at the spring controller but didnt help

Comment: I followed a suggestion and created a wrapper class as shown below

public class ConsumerPriceWrapper {
 List<ConsumerPrice> listConsumerPrice;
}

Then in the Spring controller, I added as below but still doesnt work

public ArrayList<ConsumerPrice> updateQuotes(@RequestBody ConsumerPriceWrapper updatedItems,ConsumerPrice consumerPrice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve this. There is nothing in the spring controller but i changed the way we pass the Javascript array from Angular controller.

The first 2 lines down below is the difference on how I add the list to formdata array. That helped me to fetch the values in Spring Controller.

```
$scope.formData = [];
$scope.formData = $scope.cQuoteList;
$http.post('updateQuotes', $scope.formData).success(function(response) {
        $scope.userQuotes();
});
```